# Change variable within SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm running a simple while loop that executes a stored procedure given a condition. Is there any way to access the stored procedure variable and change a variable within it before it executes? The variable I want to change is the same as the `@date` variable.

Thanks for any help guys.

```
declare @dayscount int
Declare @date as date

set @dayscount = 256
set @date = cast(GETDATE() - @dayscount as Date);

while (@dayscount >= 1)
   exec A

set @dayscount = @dayscount - 1
```

Comment: Modify the stored procedure to take an argument and pass `@date` in as an argument when you call it.

Comment: No there's no (practical) way to do that. You need to add it as an input parameter to your stored procedure. You can probably alter your SP code at runtime but I only include that for completeness. It's a really really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can try recursion in a CTE if all you are doing is decrementing or dynamic sql within your stored procedure and the replace function to replace the variable with the values you want and then run the execute_sql stored procedure within your stored procedure.